# AWS Cognito - SerializationException (Start of structure or map found where not expected)

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have created a user in Cognito user pool, using the create user option as shown in the image, and want that user to set a new password on first Log In. For this I am using below given method, as given in the AWS documents
[Create User from AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ote.png)

> cognitouser.completeNewPasswordChallenge()

Below is my code

```
//Start: setNewPasswordForAdmin
    setNewPasswordForAdmin(username: string, password: string) {

        //Start: Creating new user with username and pool data
        const adminUserdata = {
            Username: username,
            Pool: userpoolAdmin
        }
        const adminuser = new CognitoUser(adminUserdata);
        //End: Creating new user with username and pool data


        //create attributelist array which will contain all the attributes requried for signing in
        //these attributes are those attributes, which are selected while creating user pool on aws
        const attributeList : CognitoUserAttribute[] = [];

        //form a json object containing Name and Value of attribute used
        const usernameattribute = {
            Name:'username',
            Value: username
        }

        //Push list of attributes in the attributeList array
        attributeList.push(new CognitoUserAttribute(usernameattribute));
        console.log(attributeList);
        const that = this;

        adminuser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(password, attributeList ,{
            onFailure(err){

                console.log(err);
            },
            onSuccess(result){
                console.log(":::::::: Password change successfull ");

                that.router.navigate(['']);
            }
        });
    }
    //End: setNewPasswordForAdmin
```

After executing this I get an error saying,

> {code: "SerializationException", name: "SerializationException",
>   message: "Start of structure or map found where not expected."}

These are the attributes which I have selected in User Pool

[List Of Attributes and permissions in user pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG6eB.png)

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it ended up being malformed data being sent to my `resetPassword` helper. The function was looking for three parameters (`username`, `code`, `password`):

```
export default function (username, code, password) {
    …
}
```

… and I was sending them as an object:

```
yield call(authResetPassword, {
    code: DOMPurify.sanitize(verificationCode),
    username: DOMPurify.sanitize(email),
    password: DOMPurify.sanitize(newPassword),
})
```

I just updated the helper and I was all set!

```
export default function ({ username, code, password }) {
    …
}
```

Just log your data in the `setNewPasswordForAdmin` function and I’ll bet you’ll find something awry there.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Due to OP's function parameter types, it wouldn't execute unless both params are String. They weren't in my case, so the issue was different. However, when one googles this error message, this page comes up, so I leave my original answer below in case others have the same issue as I had:

I had (edit: **almost**) the same problem. As I understand now, this response is possible on various AWS APIs and it's not specific to Cognito, although I was working with a Cognito client app as well.

This response is sent when your request body contains variables of the wrong type, e.g. Boolean instead of string (or in my case, object instead of string).

However, Knowing this alone didn't help me.
I was working with Vue.js, sending input element's values using `CognitoUserPool.completeNewPasswordChallenge` and `CognitoUserPool.signUp` methods of amazon-cognito-identity-js. The request looked good in Chrome, the values seemed ok in Vue dev tools, and Amazon's error message was cryptic and undocumented.

The problem was that I sent the input element nodes themselves rather than the values of them: `variableName` instead of `this.variableName`.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the case here. The code would not compile if he tried to give html element's as argument for that service method when it's taking in only strings.

Comment: I adjusted my reply accordingly. Since this error is rarely discussed on the internet and this very page comes up when one googles the issue, I leave my original answer for others, with added disclaimer that this is in fact not the solution to OP's exact case.